# Get kendo MVC grid Row data while clicking image icon inside row

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

[image]

please find above image. in above image for first record there is a history image is there.  for second row there is no history image.

so here is my requirement.

when i click that history icon i want to  pass resource name, dept, project, charge description to action and get history values for that  record. and i want to display those history values in grid in model pop up. here in my handler method how can i get current kendo grid row data.

below is my code.

```html
columns.Bound(p => p.HoursYTD).Width(70).Filterable(false).Editable("function() {return false;}").ClientFooterTemplate("#=kendo.toString(sum, '0,0')#").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" })
 .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "white-space: normal; text-align: center;font-weight: bold;" }).
ClientTemplate("#= DisplayImage(data) #");
```

```js
<script>
    function DisplayImage(product) {
        //alert(product.IsHistory);
        //alert(product.HoursYTD);
    //var action = '@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Product")';
        if (product.IsHistory=="Yes")
            var html = kendo.format(product.HoursYTD +"<img src='/Images/" + product.IsHistory + ".png' height='22' width='22'  onclick='myHandler(event)'");
        else
            var html = kendo.format("<div>"+product.HoursYTD+"</div>");

    return html;
}
 function myHandler(e) {
    alert("hello");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the underlying data item happens by passing the TR HTML element to the [dataItem() method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/dataitem) of the grid:

```
function myHandler(e) {
    var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var dataItem = $("#grid").getKendoGrid().dataItem(row); // swap 'grid' with the name of your grid
    // access properties via dataItem.FieldName;
}
```